# Will my cat Mitch stop growing now that he is almost 2 years old?

Tags: cats, growing

I wanted to know if my little boy Mitch (a male American short-haired) will stop growing now that he is roughly around 1.5 to 2 years old and weighs around 17 lbs (might be overfed a little) and he has been neutered.

Comment: is your cat an indoor only cat,have you changed the type of food to one for spayed/neutered cats,for a normal sized cat allmost 8 kg is above what is ideal for a two year old cat.

Comment: Clarification: Is your cat an American Shorthair (a recognized breed from a breeder), or a domestic shorthair (mixed breed) from America?

Answer (score 4):

In general, cats stop growing when they are one year old; this means your cat will not get longer or taller, and the growth stop is gradual, not a sudden stop.

In [this article on pets.thenest.com](https://pets.thenest.com/kitten-considered-fully-grown-4251.html) you could find more information about growth of cats.

A cat will continue to develop for another year until it looks like an adult cat, but the changes are relative small.

I am a little concerned about the weight of your cat; a two year old cat is normally not overweight due to the normal playfulness at this age and the energy used when it plays.

Here is the [article about American short-haired cats on cattime.com](http://cattime.com/cat-breeds/american-shorthair) that contains some more information.

You need to give the cat a food formulated for spayed/neutered cats, establish fixed feeding times and do not feed more than the instruction on the package says.

You have to stop giving treats to your cat, or at least only give treats once a week, and do not feed your cat foodscraps at all.

I am not saying you do any of this, so please see this as a general advice.

And last: play more with your cat and keep him active more of the time, maybe give him more/other toys. Cats like variation when they play, so they do not get bored.

Comment: Mitch begs for treats in the middle of the night by pestering me and my mother until we get up and give him three or four treats to quiet him down, my mom is in charge of feeding him and we use a saucer dish to put his food in and my mom makes sure to fill it so she cant see the bottom. An sometimes when we are pouring food into his bowl he gets under the bag aching his back making more food spill out, we feed him often one, two times a day, at night he is running around like he is possessed he does it during the day, i am not worried about him not exercising or anything.

Comment: I told my mom that we need to get him a bowl actually meant for cant food as it was smaller/easier to clean and would help us cut back on over feeding him accidentally.

Comment: @Maski it is important to not give treats at night if you do this he will wake you every night,if you want your cat to stay healthy you have to feed him only the amount given on the foodpackage,an overweight cat will get health problems when he gets older,cats can live for 20years and it is up to you to make those years as good as possible.